# Rails: set default record if none assigned or if relation removed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've got a model called `Brand`, on which several things rely including in this example a model called `User`. If a `Brand` is deleted then a lot of things will fail. What's the best way to set a default `Brand` for all its relationships in the event that a `Brand` is deleted?

I thought writing stuff like this might work:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :assign_to_default_brand, :if => :not_branded?

  def not_branded?
    !self.brand_id?
  end

  def assign_to_default_brand
    self.brand_id = Brand.first
  end

end
```

But it doesn't seem to behave the way I want it to. Is there a best-practice established here? Cheers.

**UPDATED**

I've thrown a `default` boolean onto `Brand` and written this but again it seems to have no effect. Am I missing something?

```
class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :assign_users_to_default

  def assign_users_to_default
    self.users.all.each { |user| user.brand_id = Brand.where(:default => true).first.id if user.not_branded? }
  end

end
```

Comment: is there any association between the two models

Comment: A `Brand` has many `Users`; a `User` has one `Brand`.

Answer (score 1):

It should be a `before_save` instead of `after_save`   That way the value will be persisted to the database when the instance is saved.

For deletion on a brand you could use `after_destroy`

```
class Brand
  after_destroy :switch_assigned_users

  def switch_assigned_users
    User.where(:brand_id => id).update_all(:brand_id => Brand.first)
  end
end
```

This finds all users that assigned to that brand and switches them to the first one.

Comment: I like the idea. If I deselect a user from Brand though the user record isn't updated with the `before_save` callback. Any ideas?